# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration

Tags: java, docker, java-11, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I have a docker image called myImageName:latest, which I use in my application.
I want to write an integration test for my application, therefore I want to use the TestContainer package. When I run the following simple test:

```
@Testcontainers
public class myIntegrationTest{

    @Container
    private GenericContainer container =
    new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("myImageName:latest"))
    .withExposedPorts(8080);

    
    @Test
    public void myIntegrationTestName() throws Exception{
        assertTrue(container.isRunning());
    }

}
```

I get the following error (full stacktrace):

> 18:30:58.741 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
> 2
> 18:30:58.746 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception NoClassDefFoundError (Could not initialize class org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultObjectMapperHolder)
> 18:30:58.747 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
> at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:215)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
> at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:207)
> at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:136)
> at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:178)
> at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
> at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
> at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)
> at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242)
> at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229)
> at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$4(TestcontainersExtension.java:82)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:205)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$closeAllStoredCloseableValues$1(ExtensionValuesStore.java:65)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3605)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.closeAllStoredCloseableValues(ExtensionValuesStore.java:68)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.AbstractExtensionContext.close(AbstractExtensionContext.java:74)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.JupiterEngineExecutionContext.close(JupiterEngineExecutionContext.java:53)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.cleanUp(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:222)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.cleanUp(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:148)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.cleanUp(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$cleanUp$9(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.cleanUp(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:87)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

- docker v20.10.5
- junit v5.7
- TestContainer v1.15.3
- jdk v11.0.10

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There should be some other previous log messages before that stacktrace, please check them, the reason should be there.

Comment: Hi Vitaly, thanks for your comment. I edited the post, added the logs previous to the error.

Comment: `org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception NoClassDefFoundError (Could not initialize class org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultObjectMapperHolder`

Answer (score 3):

I added the following dependency to the pom.xml:

> ```
> <dependency>
>  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
>  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
>  <version>2.10.5</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

This package has the missing class:

> DefaultObjectMapperHolder

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar exception when using rancher desktop. To check if docker was running okay I ran

```
$ docker compose ls
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

With this information, I concluded that there was an issue with the rancher desktop docker environment.
On restarting rancher desktop, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Start the docker desktop application in background.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For MacOs, I downloaded docker desktop and ran it. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/

When I ran the test, it worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).